# Export peak positions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, position, r4photobiology

I am new in R and I hope I can clealy express my request.

I used the function `stat_peaks` included in ggspectra (extensions to 'ggplot2' for Radiation Spectra) to find at which x positions peaks are located. This function gives a nice visualization of the peaks, but I would like to export/save in a dataframe these peak positions.

Example. I have two spectra (sample1 and sample2) with two peaks. I use `stat_peaks` and I can see that the peaks are located in sample 1 at positions 209 and 467 and in sample 2 at positions 213 and 468. I would like to obtain a dataframe for those peaks like this:

```
ID          x       y (intensity)
sample1   209      1050
sample1   467      2250
sample2   213      850
sample2   468      1300
```

Then I can use this data frame to plot the data in different ways.

Do you know if it is possible to obtain something similar?

Thank you in advance
Agnese

Comment: Can you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding some data and the code you're using?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems like function `photobiology::find_peaks()` from `photobiology` is that you're looking for. Read about it here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggspectra/vignettes/userguide1-grammar.html#peaks-valleys-and-target-values

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @atsyplenkov! I looked at `photobiology::find_peaks()` and then I found `photobiology::get_peaks()`, which does exactly what I wanted.  [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/photobiology/versions/0.9.4/topics/get_peaks]

Comment: `ggspectra::stat_peaks()` calls the functions from package 'photobiology'.  There is a variation of the stat `ggpp::stat_peaks()` that is not aimed at spectral data, and supports numeric and time on the x axis and is thus usable with time series data. The work in all these functions is done by `splus2R::peaks()`.